# How do I display a chart with chart.js?

Tags: html, chart.js

Thank you for your time to read my doubt. I am trying to show the example bar chart from chartjs.org but it doesn't display in my browser. There is no problem showing in the console. I can't see my error. Can someone help me on this one? 
Thank you very much!

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<!-- <script src="chart.js"></script> -->
```

Comment: Hey Angel, I've tried your code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9p2qvdr/) and I can see it just fine. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Hey Sebas! Thank you very much for your help! I am using Google Chrome. I added a <div> to the <canvas> tag (<div><canvas></canvas></div>) and it solve my problem. I don't know why tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey there i checked your code and it works fine maybe you did not include jquery 
try adding this before adding the charts cdn

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

i have added a fiddle as an example for you to reference please check
https://jsfiddle.net/og3xy7mb/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I solve it adding a <div> before the <canva> tag like this: 
<div><canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas></div>.

I don't understand why that solve the problem. I will add the script you mention too! :)